# javascript array of objects - redistribute

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const current = [
{ studentName: 'Name', ItemNumber: 1, Score: 0 }, 
{ studentName: 'Name', ItemNumber: 2, Score: 1 }]

const needed = [
{ studentName: 'Name', Item1Score: 0, Item2Score: 1 }
]

const names = [...new Set(current.map(v=>v.studentName))]
const items = [...new Set(current.map(v=>v.ItemNumber))].length
```

How can I convert the current array to the one I need? I know how to get individual student names and the number of items but I don't know how to combine this info in an efficient way to get the needed array.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: eventually I will use the new array (const needed) as part of a data grid: https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll want to collect all students by name, then start combining properties based on that `ItemNumber`

```js
const current = [
{ studentName: 'Name', ItemNumber: 1, Score: 0 }, 
{ studentName: 'Name', ItemNumber: 2, Score: 1 }]

const map = current.reduce((map, { studentName, ItemNumber, ...props }) => {
  // collect by studentName
  return map.set(studentName, {
    ...(map.get(studentName) ?? {}), // merge any previously found entries
    ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(props).map(([ key, val ]) =>
      [ `Item${ItemNumber}${key}`, val ]))
  })
}, new Map())

const needed = Array.from(map, ([ studentName, data ]) => ({
  studentName,
  ...data
}))

console.info(needed)
```

This takes any property that is not `studentName` or `ItemNumber` and prefixes it with *"Item<ItemNumber>"* so if you have properties other that `Score`, it will also work for those.

Comment: this is a great answer as it goes above and beyond the requirements. I can now have access to all the values related to the student instead of just item 1 and item 2 scores.

Comment: one additional question: how would you edit the response to allow for an aggregation of all scores per student so that the needed array now looks like this:  const needed = [
{ studentName: 'Name', TotalScore: 1, Item1Score: 0, Item2Score: 1 }
]

Answer (score -1):

Use `Array.reduce()` to compose a dictionary object of both sets of scores referenced by student name. Then convert the dictionary object into an array of objects in the requested format using a combination of `Object.entries()` and `Array.map()`.

```
const current = [
{ studentName: 'Name', ItemNumber: 1, Score: 0 }, 
{ studentName: 'Name', ItemNumber: 2, Score: 1 }];

const neededDict = current.reduce((acc, {studentName, ItemNumber, Score})=>{
        acc[studentName][`item${ItemNumber}Score`] = Score;
    }), {});

const needed = Object.entries(neededDict).map(([key, value])=>{
    return {
        studentName: key,
        Item1Score: value.Item1Score,
        Item2Score: value.Item2Score
    };
}
console.log(needed);
```